# Dynamic div content heigh animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a dynamic content:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dynamic">
  </div>
</div>

var imgPath = '/images/' + Math.random();
$('.dynamic').html('<img style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="'+ imgPath +'">');

$('.parent').animate({ height: ??? });
```

This code is called in click handler. How to get the height of `dynamic` div with new content inside?

Comment: Why not `$(".dynamic").height()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
$('.parent').animate({ height: $('.dynamic').innerHeight()+'px'});
```

Comment: could return 0 if image not fully loaded

Comment: And in case when there is not only image? For example, some text after image.

Comment: @A.Wolff All images are preloaded.

Comment: Why should have to give height of outer div, because outer div automatically set height of inner divs.

Comment: So, i guess see @RGraham's comment but you could have more than one parent and dynamic elements, who knows?...

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do:

```
$(this).find(".dynamic").height()
```

or

```
$(".dynamic", this).height()
```

so should be:

```
$('.parent').animate({ height: $(this).find(".dynamic").height() });
```